# Master Degree or Job?

Tags: education

I am recent graduate from a UK university in computer science. As I am not sure what to study for my master degree, I went for a Web-Developer graduate job, and got accepted. As I will probably go for a master in 1-2 years, I was wondering if my undergraduate degree will be consider useless. And my master degree will possibly have nothing to do with the job I am currently accepted for. For example if I choose to do a master degree in computer graphics. Will that be a problem? (I have modules related to computer graphics in my degree, so my question is that will they be still valuable after 1-2 years as computer technology changes everyday) help? thanks!

(this may not be the best forum in stack exchange to ask these, but it is the closest)

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the latest/greatest degree you have is considered the most important.

Technology does change quickly, but principles change less rapidly. So if you have a good degree, it won't matter so much that technology changes. If you know the principles, then you can learn new technologies and more advanced concepts. If you only know how to use some specific set of tool, then you might have trouble as technology evolves.

In general, a masters degree may help you get a better initial job, especially if you want to do something specialised, such as computer graphics, security or data mining, but once you have a job your experience will matter most, not your grades or degree.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that an advanced degree gives you better opportunities for promotion within a company. For example, without managerial education (the oft-despised MBA) you can't reasonably hope to land a mid-level management position.